# Relationship between groups and spaces

Tags: group-theory, vector-spaces, terminology

From the definition on Wikipedia: In mathematics, a [space](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_(mathematics)) is a set (sometimes called a universe) with some added structure.
 A group seems to satisfy this definition. For example, we know that Lie groups are differentiable manifolds.

So my question is: is it proper to say that a group is also a kind of spaces, just like vector spaces and topological spaces, but with different or simpler structure?

Comment: It would help if you linked to the article in question.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  That article says "you often think of a 'space' as more geometric and a 'structure' as more algebraic" and "groups are algebraic"

Comment: "Space" is just a generic term without any specified meaning. So no, I would not say that a group is a kind of space. It is true that it is a "set with some added structure", but this doesn't really tell you anything, and is not consistent with how the term "space" is normally used.

Comment: You *could* say that... but almost nobody does. The structure on groups is a bit stronger (it consists of **operations**). The usual generic name for “a set with a bunch of operations defined on it” is **algebra** (in the sense of Universal Algebra), which encompasses vector spaces, semigroups, rings, monoids, modules, lattices, and many other structures. That would be the usual level of generality applied in that instance.

Comment: I have voted to reopen this question, as I cannot see any issue with it. It reads as an honest "I read this and got wondering..." question, which is the kind of question we should be encouraging!

Answer (score 2):

Sure, it can be useful to attempt to think about mathematical concepts in a way that goes against the grain a little bit. Here are a few ways of thinking of groups as spaces. I suppose it should go without saying that these are very useful ways of thinking about groups.

There are *topological groups,* which you could define as topological spaces that admit the structure of a group, or  as groups where the defining features (multiplication, inversion) are continuous maps. As you mention, Lie groups  are a good example of topological groups. Of course, any group may be given the discrete topology, but even  this is relevant, for instance, in some definitions of a *properly discontinuous* group action.

Another topology that any group can be given is the [profinite topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residually_finite_group), where a neighborhood basis  of the identity in $G$ is the set of finite index subgroups of $G$. Useful properties of infinite groups, like residual finiteness, are topological statements about the profinite topology.

If $S$ is a generating set for a group $G$, $G$ can be given the *word metric*, $d_S$, where $d_S(g,h)$ is the  minimum number of elements of $S$ required to write  $gh^{-1}$ in terms  of this basis. Although this gives every group the discrete topology, when $S$ is a finite set, one can learn quite a lot about $G$ from $d_S$,  at least as distances go to infinity! (This is a starting  point for [geometric group theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_group_theory).)

Comment: Although this is less literal than the OP may be looking for, there’s also a sense in which a group $G$ could be seen as geometric actions on a space — and $G$ can become identified with the space itself. If the action is free and transitive, this example becomes more literal as the geometric action is equivalent to $G$ acting on the space of its cosets of the kernel.